# Change master fails when migrating to Google SQL

Tags: mysql, database-replication, google-cloud-sql

I am migrating my active site's database to google and want to set up Google SQL as a replication slave to my existing MySQL database. I uploaded the whole 25GB database, and then went to enable replication, but got this error:

> mysql> change master to master_host='*REDACTED*', master_user='*REDACTED*', master_password='*REDACTED*';
>
> ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

I am stuck now with a database and service I can't use. I'd like to get these replicated so that I can migrate my app over next, get it working on the replicated slave, and then turn off my old provider.

Any suggestions on how to do this would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies - Cloud SQL does not have the ability to act as a slave to an on-premises database yet. A workaround is to use something like dbshards to perform the migration: http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2014/02/using-dbshards-and-cloud-sql-to-provide.html

Comment: I don't think dbshards is free software. Can you recommend another way to do this? Why is it I can't get 'super' privilege on my database?

Comment: Sorry I don't have other recommendations. See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-cloud-sql-announce/-9oscPshaME/6NTGK8q4lvUJ for super privilege removal notice.

Comment: Is there a way to create a ticket so that some google admin can just change these settings on my database one time? How can I reach Joe Faith, the author of this message, who said that he'd like to hear from me so he can find a workaround for this problem?